# Is the CV-22 / MV-22 Osprey classified as a helicopter, plane or both?

Tags: military, v-22, head-of-state-transport, air-force-one, marine-one

1. Is the CV-22 / MV-22 Osprey classified as a helicopter, plane or both?
2. If the President had to hitch a ride on one, would it become **Airforce One** (CV-22) or **Marine One** (MV-22)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are classified as Tiltrotors, which is its own category for all the obvious reasons.

If the President were flying in a Marine Osprey, the callsign would be Marine One. If he were in an Air Force Osprey, it'd be Air Force One.

Comment: FAA category is "Powered Lift." See FAR 61.5

Comment: "Tiltrotor" is one of the configurations of "Powered Lift." Other configurations of the Powered Lift category include "Lift Fan" and "Vectored Thrust." So, the Osprey does not fall under the Rotorcraft category (helicopter-class) or the Airplane category. It's   a Powered Lift category without a specific FAA defined FAR Part 61 class.

Answer (score 11):

1. Under the FAA, a CV/MV-22 Osprey is considered to be a powered lift aircraft. Under [14 CFR §1.1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/1.1):

   > Powered-lift means a heavier-than-air aircraft capable of vertical takeoff, vertical landing, and low speed flight that depends principally on engine-driven lift devices or engine thrust for lift during these flight regimes and on nonrotating airfoil(s) for lift during horizontal flight.
2. That designation would depend on the branch of service operating the aircraft.  A USAF CV-22 carrying the President would have the call sign Air Force One during the operation.  A USMC MV-22 carrying the President would have the call sign Marine One.